# Ruby gem command crash shell Fastlane & Cocoapods

Tags: ruby, rubygems, cocoapods, fastlane

I am having issues running fastlane and cocoapods for a month now. Any idea what is the issue? Tried RVM, changing the version and so on but nothing works.

I reinstalled fastlane then cocopoda started working again. Now fastlane does not work, error below.

```
 It seems like you wanted to load some plugins, however they couldn't be loaded
[22:05:14]: Please follow the troubleshooting guide: https://docs.fastlane.tools/plugins/plugins-troubleshooting/
Traceback (most recent call last):
    8: from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `<main>'
    7: from /usr/local/bin/fastlane:23:in `load'
    6: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.170.0/bin/fastlane:23:in `<top (required)>'
    5: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.170.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/cli_tools_distributor.rb:119:in `take_off'
    4: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.170.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:41:in `start'
    3: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.170.0/fastlane/lib/fastlane/commands_generator.rb:352:in `run'
    2: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/delegates.rb:15:in `run!'
    1: from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/fastlane-2.170.0/fastlane_core/lib/fastlane_core/ui/fastlane_runner.rb:50:in `run!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/commander-fastlane-4.4.6/lib/commander/runner.rb:411:in `parse_global_options': ambiguous option: --v (OptionParser::AmbiguousOption)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't see how you're invoking Fastlane. That said, it's probably that you are running `fastlane --v` and not `fastlane -v`:

```bash
$ fastlane --help
...
-v, --version        Display version information
```